# A constexpr, const correct matrix class with compile-time checks

Tags: c++, matrix, c++20

I've expanded, and enhanced my matrix class which uses, aside from dynamic memory for the elements, only 3, const literals. These are rows, cols, and a ptr. The methods are all constexpr and the example code includes compile time verification of tests which compare compile time hashes against hashes generated at runtime. Since compile time execution is much better at detecting UB this seemed desirable as using consts in classes is rather new and not really viable pre c++20. This code no longer uses `construct_at` on sub-objects but only on full objects which is more clearly legal in c++20.

[this was the previous version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/278137/a-matrix-class-using-const-members) I have incorporated many of the suggestions other commenters have made.

I also made a transpose method using a single loop with pointers expecting it to be faster than the version looping over both rows and cols. To my surprise it wasn't and came in 25% slower! That code is in the transpose2 method.

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ffeY67e1b)

matrix2d.h

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <numeric>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace matrix_const
{

    template <typename T>
    class Matrix2D {
        T* const pv;
    public:
        const size_t cols;
        const size_t rows;
        using type = T;
        constexpr Matrix2D() noexcept : pv(nullptr), cols(0), rows(0) {}
        // uninitialized matrix. All values must be set priot to reading/using any
        explicit constexpr Matrix2D(size_t a_rows, size_t a_cols) :
            pv(new T[a_rows * a_cols]), cols(a_cols), rows(a_rows) {}
        // value initialized matrix
        explicit constexpr Matrix2D(size_t a_rows, size_t a_cols, T init) :
            pv(new T[a_rows * a_cols]), cols(a_cols), rows(a_rows) {
            std::fill(pv, pv + rows * cols, init);
        }
        // object only raw ctor for use with std::construct_at
        explicit constexpr Matrix2D(T* pv, size_t cols, size_t rows) : pv(pv), cols(cols), rows(rows) {}

        explicit constexpr Matrix2D(const Matrix2D& rhs) : pv(new T[rhs.rows * rhs.cols]), cols(rhs.cols), rows(rhs.rows) {
            std::copy(rhs.pv, rhs.pv + rows * cols, pv);
        }
        constexpr Matrix2D& operator=(const Matrix2D& rhs) {
            if (this != &rhs)
            {
                if (cols * rows != rhs.cols * rhs.rows) // skip delete/new if mem size unchanged
                {
                    T* newp = new T[rhs.rows * rhs.cols];    // if new fails, *this is unchanged
                    delete[] pv;
                    std::construct_at(this, newp, rhs.cols, rhs.rows);
                }
                std::copy(rhs.pv, rhs.pv + rows * cols, pv);
            }
            return *this;
        }
        constexpr Matrix2D(Matrix2D&& rhs) noexcept : pv(rhs.pv), cols(rhs.cols), rows(rhs.rows) {
            std::construct_at(&rhs, nullptr, 0, 0);     // set rhs to a valid, null matrix
        }
        constexpr Matrix2D& operator=(Matrix2D&& rhs) noexcept {
            delete[] pv;
            std::construct_at(this, rhs.pv, rhs.cols, rhs.rows);    // grab rhs's guts
            std::construct_at(&rhs, nullptr, 0, 0);                 // set rhs to a valid, null matrix
            return *this;
        }
        constexpr ~Matrix2D() {
            delete[] pv;
        }

        // additional ctor to provide list initialization
        constexpr Matrix2D(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> list) :
            pv(new T[list.size() * (list.begin())->size()]{}),
            cols((list.begin())->size()),
            rows(list.size())
        {
            if (rows > 0 && cols > 0)
                for (size_t row = 0; row < list.size(); row++)
                {
                    if (list.begin()->size() != (list.begin() + row)->size())
                        throw std::runtime_error("number of columns in each row must be the same");
                    for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++)
                        pv[cols * row + col] = *((list.begin() + row)->begin() + col);
                }
            else
                std::construct_at(this, nullptr, 0, 0);
        }

        // bracket access v[r][c]
        constexpr T* operator[](size_t row) noexcept { return pv + row * cols; }
        constexpr const T* operator[](size_t row) const noexcept { return pv + row * cols; }

        // paren access v(r,c);
        constexpr T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) noexcept { return pv[row * cols + col]; }
        constexpr const T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) const noexcept { return pv[row * cols + col]; }

        // insert a sub-matrix by overlaying a selected portion, returns the whole matrix
        constexpr Matrix2D insert_matrix(const Matrix2D& mat, size_t row_start, size_t col_start) const
        {
            if (row_start + mat.rows > rows || col_start + mat.cols > cols)
                throw std::range_error("Requested extents exceed bounds");
            Matrix2D ret(*this);
            for (size_t row = row_start; row < row_start + mat.rows; row++)
                for (size_t col = col_start; col < col_start + mat.cols; col++)
                    ret(row, col) = mat(row - row_start, col - col_start);
            return ret;
        }

        // return a matrix subset
        constexpr Matrix2D get_sub_matrix(size_t row_start, size_t col_start, size_t row_count, size_t col_count) const
        {
            Matrix2D ret(row_count, col_count);
            if (row_start + row_count > rows || col_start + col_count > cols)
                throw std::range_error("Requested extents exceed bounds");
            for (size_t row = row_start; row < row_start + row_count; row++)
                for (size_t col = col_start; col < col_start + col_count; col++)
                    ret[row - row_start][col - col_start] = (*this)(row, col);
            return ret;
        }

        // negate
        constexpr Matrix2D operator-() const
        {
            Matrix2D ret(rows, cols);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
                ret.pv[i] = -pv[i];
            return ret;
        }

        // add
        constexpr friend Matrix2D operator+(const Matrix2D& lhs, const Matrix2D& rhs)
        {
            if (lhs.cols != rhs.cols && lhs.rows != rhs.rows)
                throw std::range_error("matrixes must have same dims");
            Matrix2D ret(lhs);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < ret.rows * ret.cols; i++)
                ret.pv[i] += rhs.pv[i];
            return ret;
        }
        // add +=
        constexpr Matrix2D& operator+=(const Matrix2D& lhs)
        {
            if (lhs.cols != cols && lhs.rows != rows)
                throw std::range_error("matrixes must have same dims");
            for (size_t i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
                pv[i] += lhs.pv[i];
            return *this;
        }
        // subtract
        constexpr friend Matrix2D operator-(const Matrix2D& lhs, const Matrix2D& rhs)
        {
            if (lhs.cols != rhs.cols && lhs.rows != rhs.rows)
                throw std::range_error("matrixes must have same dims");
            Matrix2D ret(lhs);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < ret.rows * ret.cols; i++)
                ret.pv[i] -= rhs.pv[i];
            return ret;
        }
        // sub -=
        constexpr Matrix2D& operator-=(const Matrix2D& lhs)
        {
            if (lhs.cols != cols && lhs.rows != rows)
                throw std::range_error("matrixes must have same dims");
            for (size_t i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
                pv[i] -= lhs.pv[i];
            return *this;
        }

        // This optimizes into just one loop yet is slower than
        // the simple version using ret(c, r) = rhs(r, c);
        constexpr Matrix2D transpose2() const
        {
            Matrix2D ret(cols, rows);    // shape is flipped
            T* p = pv;
            T* pend = pv + rows * cols;
            T* tp = ret.pv;
            T* tpstart = tp;
            T* tpend = ret.pv + rows * cols;
            while (p < pend)
            {
                *tp = *p++;
                tp += rows;
                if (tp >= tpend)
                    tp = ++tpstart;
            }
            return ret;
        }

        // transpose
        constexpr Matrix2D transpose() const
        {
            Matrix2D<T> ret(cols, rows, 0);
            for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++)
                for (size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++)
                {
                    auto r1 = r;
                    auto c1 = c;
                    ret(c, r) = operator()(r, c);
                }
            return ret;
        }

        // append new columns
        constexpr Matrix2D append_columns(const Matrix2D& new_cols) const
        {
            if (rows != new_cols.rows)
                throw std::range_error("appended matrix must have same number of rows");
            Matrix2D<T> ret(rows, cols + new_cols.cols);
            for (size_t r = 0; r < ret.rows; r++)
                for (size_t c = 0; c < ret.cols; c++)
                    if (c < cols)
                        ret(r, c) = operator()(r, c);
                    else
                        ret(r, c) = new_cols(r, c - cols);
            return ret;
        }

        // append new rows
        constexpr Matrix2D append_rows(const Matrix2D& new_rows) const
        {
            if (cols != new_rows.cols)
                throw std::range_error("appended matrix must have same number of columns");
            Matrix2D<T> ret(rows + new_rows.rows, cols);
            for (size_t r = 0; r < ret.rows; r++)
                for (size_t c = 0; c < ret.cols; c++)
                    if (r < rows)
                        ret(r, c) = operator()(r, c);
                    else
                        ret(r, c) = new_rows(r - rows, c);
            return ret;
        }

        constexpr Matrix2D invert() const
        {
            if (rows != cols)
                throw std::range_error("cols and rows must be the same");
            auto ident = Matrix2D(rows, rows, 0);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                ident(i, i) = 1;
            Matrix2D m = this->append_columns(ident);
            for (size_t i = m.rows - 1; i > 0; i--)
                //Swap rows to put largest initial element first
                if (m[i - 1][0] < m[i][0])
                    for (size_t j = 0; j < m.cols; j++)
                        std::swap(m[i][j], m[i - 1][j]);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < m.rows; i++)
            {
                for (size_t j = 0; j < m.rows; j++)
                {
                    if (j != i)
                    {
                        if (m[i][i] == 0)
                            throw std::domain_error("singular");
                        T temp = m[j][i] / m[i][i];
                        for (size_t k = 0; k < 2 * m.rows; k++)
                            m[j][k] -= m[i][k] * temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (size_t i = 0; i < m.rows; i++)
            {
                T temp = m[i][i];
                for (size_t j = 0; j < 2 * m.rows; j++)
                    m[i][j] = m[i][j] / temp;
            }
            return m.get_sub_matrix(0, m.rows, m.rows, m.rows);
        }
    };

    // multiply matrixes
    template <typename T>
    constexpr Matrix2D<T> operator*(const Matrix2D<T>& lhs, const Matrix2D<T>& rhs)
    {
        if (lhs.cols != rhs.rows)
            throw std::range_error("cols of first must == rows of second");
        Matrix2D<T> ret(lhs.rows, rhs.cols);
        Matrix2D<T> mat_tmp = rhs.transpose();     // transpose to improve cache locality
        for (size_t row = 0; row < lhs.rows; row++)
            for (size_t col = 0; col < rhs.cols; col++)
                ret[row][col] = std::inner_product(lhs[row], lhs[row] + lhs.cols, mat_tmp[col], T(0));
        return ret;
    }

    // equality test
    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator==(const Matrix2D<T>& lhs, const Matrix2D<T>& rhs)
    {
        if (lhs.cols != rhs.cols || lhs.rows != rhs.rows)
            return false;
        for (size_t row = 0; row < lhs.rows; row++)
            for (size_t col = 0; col < lhs.cols; col++)
                if (lhs(row,col) != rhs(row, col))
                    return false;
        return true;
    }
    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator!=(const Matrix2D<T>& lhs, const Matrix2D<T>& rhs)
    {
        return !(lhs==rhs);
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "matrix2d.h"

using namespace matrix_const;

struct HashList {
    unsigned int hash[100];
};

// set #if 0  to force printout of all matrixes
#if 1
constexpr HashList hashlist{
4231457547u,559445916u,3889815258u,559445916u,559445916u,559445916u,1196435762u,146730798u,2933268210u,2648446219u,
1101633479u,2648446219u,1934638098u,2735629034u,3480429190u,2106445168u,559445916u,559445916u,3480429190u,2106445168u,
559445916u,2648446219u,1101633479u,2648446219u,3682454706u,3247604110u,191436758u,2648446219u,1101633479u,2648446219u,
2526570054u, };
#else
constexpr HashList hashlist{};
#endif

template <typename T>
void print(const Matrix2D<T>& mat, const std::string& message = "")
{
    std::cout << message << "\n";
    for (size_t r = 0; r < mat.rows; r++)
    {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < mat.cols; c++)
            std::cout << mat[r][c] << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int error_count{};

template <typename T>
constexpr unsigned int matrix_hash(const Matrix2D<T>& mat, size_t &index)
{
    auto crc_cycle = [](unsigned int v, auto x) {return (std::bit_cast<unsigned int>(x) + v) * 1664525u + 1013904223u; };
    unsigned int hash{};
    hash = crc_cycle(hash, static_cast<unsigned int>(mat.rows));
    hash = crc_cycle(hash, static_cast<unsigned int>(mat.cols));
    for (size_t r = 0; r < mat.rows; r++)
        for (size_t c = 0; c < mat.cols; c++)
            hash = crc_cycle(hash, mat(r, c));
    if (!std::is_constant_evaluated() && hash != hashlist.hash[index])
    {
        print(mat, std::to_string(index) + " Matrix Difference Detected");
        error_count++;
    }
    index++;
    return hash;
}


// Generate hashes of matrixes after various tests at both runtime and compile time
// so they can be checked against each other
constexpr std::array<unsigned int, 100> do_tests()
{
    std::vector<unsigned int> hashes;
    std::array<unsigned int, 100> hashes_array{};
    size_t index{ 0 };
    using Mati = Matrix2D<int>;
    // index:0  Test initialize with fill value
    {
        Mati x(1, 2, 10);
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(x, index));
    }
    // index:1-3  Test list ctor, access with paren and [], move assignment
    {
        Mati x{ {1, 2}, { 3, 4 } };
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(x, index));
        x[0][1]++;
        x(1, 0)++;
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(x, index));
        x = Mati({ {1, 2}, { 3, 4 } });
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(x, index));
    }
    // index:4-6  Test of Move assigment operator and verification guts moved
    {
        Mati x{ {1, 2}, { 3, 4 } };
        Mati y;
        y = x;
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(y, index));
        y = std::move(x);
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(y, index));
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(x, index));   // compiler warns but this is to check gutted object remains valid
    }

    // index 7:8 Test insert and extract submatrixes
    {
        Mati x{ {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9} };
        Mati y{ {9,10},{11,12} };
        auto z = x.get_sub_matrix(0, 1, 2, 2);
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(z, index));
        auto zz = x.insert_matrix(y, 0, 1); // insert at row 0, col 1
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(zz, index));
    }

    // Index 9:11  Test transpose
    {
        Mati x = Mati{ { 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7 }, {8, 9, 10},{11,12,13} };
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(x, index));
        auto x1 = x.transpose();
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(x1, index));
        auto x2 = x1.transpose();
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(x2, index));
    }

    // Index 12:13  Test append cols, append rows
    {
        Mati x{ {1, 2}, { 3, 4 } };
        Mati y{ {5}, {6} };
        Mati z;
        z = x.append_columns(y);
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(z, index));
        z = x.append_rows(y.transpose());
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(z, index));
    }

    // Index 14:17  Test +-assignments
    {
        Mati x{ {1, 2}, { 3, 4 } }, y1, y2;
        y1 = x; y2 = x;
        y2 += y1 += x;  // note prec is left to right
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(y1, index));
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(y2, index));
        y2 -= y1 -= x;  // note prec is left to right
        y2 -= x;        // y2 == x
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(y1, index));
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(y2, index));
    }
    {
        // Index 18:20  Test + and - operators
        Mati x{ {1, 2}, { 3, 4 } }, y1, y2;
        y1 = x + x;
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(y1, index));
        y1 = y1 + x;
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(y1, index));
        y1 = y1 - x - x;    // y1 == x
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(y1, index));
    }
    {
        // Index 21:23  Test transpose
        Mati x{ { 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7 }, {8, 9, 10},{11,12,13} };
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(x, index));
        auto x1 = x.transpose();
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(x1, index));
        auto x2 = x1.transpose();
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(x2, index));
    }

    {
        // Index 24:26, float matrix inversion test
        // inversion produces small errors so any difference between compile time
        // and runtime float calcs will print associated tests
        // This may occur with different fp settings
        Matrix2D<float> x{ {1, 2}, { 3, 4 } };
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(x, index));
        auto x1 = x.invert();
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(x1, index));
        auto x2 = x1.invert();
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(x2, index));
    }

    {
        // Index 27:30 Test Transpose and multiply
        Mati x{ {1} };
        x = Mati{ { 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7 }, {8, 9, 10},{11,12,13} };
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(x, index));
        auto x1 = x.transpose();
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(x1, index));
        auto x2 = x1.transpose();
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(x2, index));
        auto x3 = x * x1;
        hashes.push_back(matrix_hash(x3, index));
    }


    // only print hashes if called at runtime and hashlist not initialized with hashes
    if (!std::is_constant_evaluated() && hashlist.hash[0] == 0)
    {
        int count{};
        for (auto x : hashes)
        {
            std::cout << x << "u,";
            if (count++ % 10 == 9)
                std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < hashes.size(); i++)
        hashes_array[i] = hashes[i];
    return hashes_array;
}


int main()
{
    // check compiler requirements for this code
    static_assert(sizeof(unsigned int) == 4 && sizeof(float) == 4);
    using namespace matrix_const;
    {
        constexpr std::array<unsigned int, 100> hash_static = do_tests();
        std::array<unsigned int, 100> hash_dynamic = do_tests();
        if (hash_dynamic != hash_static)
            throw "dynamic/static hashes don't match";
        if (hashlist.hash[0] != 0)
        {
            if (error_count)
                std::cout << error_count << " hash error(s) detected\n";
            else
                std::cout << "passed\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### OverView

Pretty sure you use of `std::construct_at()` in the copy/move assignment operator is UB.

You are doing this to try and get around `constexpr` declarations of these operations. This compiler checking is there for your safety trying to trick the compiler by using this method may shut up the messages the compiler generates but that does not mean it is a good (or valid) idea.

---

You have none standard move operators. I would expect them to be `noexcep`.

### CodeReview

So we have an owned RAW pointer.

```
        T* const pv;
```

Will pay special attention to the rule of 3/5.

---

Sure `size_t` is valid in C. But in C++ I would expect you to use `std::size_t`.

```
        const size_t cols;
        const size_t rows;
```

---

OK. You have a matrix with random data in it.

```
        explicit constexpr Matrix2D(size_t a_rows, size_t a_cols) :
            pv(new T[a_rows * a_cols]), cols(a_cols), rows(a_rows) {}
```

Not sure that is a design choice I would have made.
Might be a better choice to set the Matrix into a specific state?
I see this is the next version of the constructor. So I am wondering does this provide a real useful interface to the user.

---

You are passing in the matrix that the class will use.

```
        explicit constexpr Matrix2D(T* pv, size_t cols, size_t rows) : pv(pv), cols(cols), rows(rows) {}
```

That's a perfectly valid thing to do. **BUT** this interface does not make it clear that you are passing ownership of that data. It would be perfectly valid for the user to do this:

```
    int   data[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    Matrix2D<in> m(data, 3, 3);
```

I would change the interface to be clear that you are passing ownership of the array:

```
explicit constexpr Matrix2D(std::unique_ptr<T>&& pv,
                            size_t cols, size_t rows)
    : pv(pv)
    , cols(cols)
    , rows(rows)
{}
```

---

```
        constexpr Matrix2D& operator=(const Matrix2D& rhs) {
            .....

                    std::construct_at(this, newp, rhs.cols, rhs.rows);

            ......
            return *this;
        }
```

Not confortable with this.

This is the same as using placement new (but allowed in constexpr). This means we are calling the constructor on `this`. But `this` is an already fully formed object (its lifetme has started), so this is likely UB. This may work because of the simplicity of your object's members, **BUT** 1) I doubt it is legal (but not sure) 2) If your class becomes none trivial then this definately will not work as expected and tracking down that bug at some point in the future will be a nightmare.

You could make this valid by first calling the destructor on `this` to make sure the lifetime of the object was correctly ended before calling `std::construct_at`.

But I think it would be easier to simply swap the pointers around.

---

Same issue as above:

```
        constexpr Matrix2D(Matrix2D&& rhs) noexcept : pv(rhs.pv), cols(rhs.cols), rows(rhs.rows) {
            std::construct_at(&rhs, nullptr, 0, 0);     // set rhs to a valid, null matrix
        }
```

You are calling the constructor of an object `rhs` whose lifetime has already started.

---

Just like copy assignment, move assignment can result in assignment to self. So calling `delete[] pv` delete's the data you may be using (if is a self assignment).

Also the `std::construct_at(&rhs, nullptr, 0, 0);` will then override with null the pointer on yourself (if self assignment).

Thirdly as above the issue with `std::construct_at();` is the same as the last two cases.

---

You assume the initializer list is not empty.

```
        constexpr Matrix2D(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> list) :
            pv(new T[list.size() * (list.begin())->size()]{}),
            cols((list.begin())->size()),
            rows(list.size())
```

Remember: `list->begin()` may be equal to `list->end()` and thus `->size()` will not be valid.

---

Pre-optimization:

```
            if (rows > 0 && cols > 0)
```

Don't think it makes the code any clearer. And in the rare case when there is no data I don't think it will make the code significantly faster.

---

Comment: I had the same reservations about `std::construct_at()`, but it seems it is allowed, as long as you make sure everything ends up in a valid state? See [https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137845/discussion-between-g-sliepen-and-doug](this chat I had with doug).

Comment: @G.Sliepen I missed the const part of the issue. But the main problem is that the object is alive. So it will be destroyed first: `std::destroy_at()` to make sure the lifetime ends then you can restart the lifetime with `std::construct_at()`

Comment: @MartinYork An object's lifetime can be ended by replacing it's contents as long as there are no other side effects that explicit call to a destructor would produce. See [basic.life](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#5) Hence `std::destroy_at` is not required.

Comment: @MartinYork Why would `size()` not be valid? It's 0 when empty and that's valid in the `new` The reason I put in `if (rows > 0 && cols > 0)` was to prevent false positives which show up in MSVC's intelliense. And it only sometimes works. Had a similar (non) problem with some of the stl one-liners.

Comment: @doug `An object's lifetime can be ended by replacing it's contents as long as there are no other side effects that explicit call to a destructor`. Assuming that is true. Then, that's great for this version; but you are not considering maintainability of the code. It makes the assumption that no member will ever be added that is non trivial. **BUT** this class has a destructor with a side effect.

Comment: @doug `(list.begin())->size()` is UB if `list.begin() == list.end())`.

Comment: @MartinYork  Ah. Good catch.  s/b `cols(list.size()==0 ? 0 : (list.begin())->size()),`

Comment: @MartinYork The class is designed to be as small as possible but sure if someone added something like a `vector` or `string` to it things get quite complicated. The main one is that you can't make them `const` w/o disabling the move ops in addition to specifically destroy them as well. Major pessimization. But this is a small, simple object highly useful for matrix ops.

Comment: @doug I understand what you are trying to do. But my main goal is preventing bugs (not just now long term). For that you have to think what will happen in the future. To make your class resistant to bugs future bugs, you simply need to call `std::destroy_at()` before a call to `std::construct_at()` and now it will be safe to use now and in all situations in the future. Alternatively, you need to stack a large set of READ-ME comments somewhere to make sure future maintainers are aware of potential issues.

Comment: @MartinYork Agree about needed comments. S/B at the top of the class along with a description of general requirements for handling const subobjects. I've been trying to find the cleanest way to deal with users writing `Matrix2D<T> x{};` because initializer_list is greedy. Got one but it's uglier than I like. Normally use `std::vector` but this has 40% less object size.

Comment: I did some testing and it turns out `list.begin() == list.end())` is never true when the constructor is called. `x{}` calls the default ctor and `x{{}}` calls the the constructor with `list.size()==1` and the contained list has size 0. Improved it and posted the improvement as an answer. Also used a tag in the raw ctor to make it inaccessible to users. Code not shown. Not sure if I should just update the main post.

Answer (score 1):

## Fix compiler warnings

Enable compiler warnings and fix all of them. For GCC and Clang, I recommend using `-Wall -W -pedantic`; it doesn't warn about everything, but it's almost always free of false positives. My compiler found:

- unused variables (`r1` and `c1` in `transpose()`)
- ambiguous `else` (in `main()` in your code on godbolt)

## Simplify the constructors

You have a lot of constructors, and there is some code duplication there that can be avoided. Consider that you can have default member initialization, and that members are initialized in the order they are declared. You can initialize members not just with a constant, but any expression. So:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix2D {
public:
    const size_t cols;
    const size_t rows;
    ...
private:
    T* const pv = new T[cols * rows];
};
```

With this change, you can avoid initializing `pv` explicitly in all but two of the constructors.

## Missing `noexcept`

The "raw constructor" that takes the size and a pointer can be made `noexcept`, as it doesn't do any allocation.

## Improved access to rows

You have `operator[]` returning a pointer to the start of each row. So you could iterate over all rows using:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < matrix.rows; ++i) {
    auto row = matrix[i];
    ...
}
```

But it would be nice if a range-`for` loop would work the same way, so you can write:

```
for (auto row: matrix) {
    ...
}
```

Furthermore, it would then also be nice if you could iterate over columns using range-`for`:

```
for (auto row: matrix) {
    for (auto& element: row) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Consider having `operator[]()` not return a `T*`, but instead a `std::span<T>`:

```
constexpr std::span<T> operator[](size_t row) noexcept {
    return {pv + row * cols, cols};
}
```

And then add `begin()` and `end()` functions that return a custom iterator type, that when dereferenced also produces a `std::span<T>`.

## Provide different views

At the moment you can only access an individual element or one row at a time. Consider that you might also want to access a column at a time, or just want to iterate over all elements without regard for their position. Or perhaps you want to access a submatrix, but don't want to pay the cost of making a copy.

For getting access to all elements, consider:

```
constexpr std::span<T> data() noexcept {
    return {pv, cols * rows};
}
```

For column and submatrix access, you can't use the `std::span<>` type. Instead, you probably want to implement a custom [view type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view).

## Use more algorithms

You can make more use STL algorithms to copy things from one array to another. And if you use `std::span<T>` to represent rows, you can even use the `std::range` versions to avoid having to use `.begin()` and `.end()`. It's unfortunate that we have to wait to C++23 or beyond for things like `zip()` and `enumerate()`, this would have allowed writing even more concise code.
Consider for example:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool operator==(const Matrix2D<T>& lhs, const Matrix2D<T>& rhs)
{
    return std::ranges::equal(lhs.data(), rhs.data());
}
```

## Reduce code duplication

You can express `operator+()` and `operator+=()` in terms of each other. Consider:

```
constexpr friend Matrix2D operator+(const Matrix2D& lhs, const Matrix2D& rhs)
{
    Matrix2D ret(lhs);
    ret += rhs;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The unused variables were left overs from when I was testing some code and should have been removed. The `else` warning was fixed in the embedded code but not in the godbolt link.  Span is interesting but use of the matrix class typically involves extracting a row or col vector but as a matrix with a single row or column. Simplifies operations on vectors by enforcing alignment. The code provides extractions of these subsets on a matrix. Bracket and paren access for elements is only intended to access individual elements.

Comment: Agree on noexcept for the raw constructor and +=/+ duplication reduction..

Comment: A reason I put `pv` first is that it accesses the dynamic ram. I've noticed in code for `vector` and `string` that the dynamic ram ptr is in the first position. I suspect this may improve performance though I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I've improved the initialization list constructor:

```
// additional ctor to provide list initialization
constexpr Matrix2D(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> list) :
    pv((list.begin())->size() != 0 ? new T[list.size()*(list.begin())->size()] : nullptr),
    cols(pv != nullptr ? (list.begin())->size() : 0),
    rows(pv != nullptr ? list.size() : 0)
{
    if (pv == nullptr)
        return;
    for (size_t row = 0; row < list.size(); row++)
    {
        if (cols != (list.begin() + row)->size())
            throw std::runtime_error("number of columns in each row must be the same");
        for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++)
            pv[cols * row + col] = *((list.begin() + row)->begin() + col);
    }
}
```

Various possible initializations now work correctly and generate null Matrixes with 0 rows, 0 cols, and pv set to nullptr:

```
Matrix2D<int> a;    // default ctor
Matrix2D<int> b{};  // default ctor
Matrix2D<int> c{{}};// initializer_list ctor
```

Comment: It is legal to allocate an array of size zero with `new`. This returns a valid pointer that is not `nullptr`. It might make things a bit simpler, although you still have to check that `!list.empty()` before you can call `list.begin()`.

Comment: Generally if you are trying to improve your code you should post a follow up question with a link back to the original question rather than answering you own question.

Comment: @G.Sliepen  The initializer list is only called when `list.size() >= 1` So never empty and no check needed. However, the contained list is empty. It's a matrix with one row and zero columns.

Comment: Yes, but then consider that `constexpr Matrix2D(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> list) : pv(new T[list.size() * list.begin()->size()]), cols(list.begin()->size()), rows(list.size()) { for (...) {...} }` would also still work correctly.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Yes, however, I decided that phantom matrixes with 1 rows and zero columns need not exist and user intent almost certainly was constructing a null matrix. I wanted to keep null matrixes consistent and not have some with nullptr and others with magic numbers.